# How to aim accurately with a chopper's weaponry?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

Many of the choppers in the game are armed with various weapons, usually miniguns or rocket pods, allowing you to wreak some pretty effective devastation upon your enemies.

However actually getting rounds onto a target whilst airborne is incredibly difficult.

What techniques can I use to ensure that munitions fired from my chopper will hit the target?

Comment: Oh do I know this feeling... From the pilot seat, imo, there isn't an effective way to hit your target besides shooting while doing a flyby and hoping you hit your target.   Your best bet would be to play online, take the UH-60 (Black Hawk) Helicopter with a friend gunning on the left or right side, and stabilize the helicopter to your friend the optimal shooting path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I converted my comment into an answer as currently there isn't a way to *auto-target* an enemy from the pilot seat.

> Oh do I know this feeling... From the pilot seat, imo, there isn't an effective way to hit your target besides shooting while doing a flyby and hoping you hit your target. Your best bet would be to play online, take the UH-60 (Black Hawk) Helicopter with a friend gunning on the left or right side, and stabilize the helicopter to your friend the optimal shooting path.

UH-60:
[image]

Comment: Any ideas for solo players?

Comment: For solo, I recommend getting the Little Bird helicopter with rocket pods as  they it is easier to navigate (mobility) and there is splash damage with rockets for when you are doing your flyby attacks.

Comment: https://ghost-recon.ubisoft.com/wildlands/en-gb/news/detail.aspx?c=tcm:154-296574-16&ct=tcm:154-76770-32 Title Update 6 has brought better chopper control and an aiming reticule! :)

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to do a strafe run. Otherwise you won't get far, trying to hold position and firing.